# How to insert photo after second paragraph using coldfusion

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a variable that has a blog post with html characters in it. The content would look something like this.

I output content from a query to the page.

```
<cfoutput>#queryvar.myvar#</cfoutput>
```

I would like to know how to insert a photo after the second paragraph.

```
<img src="someimage.jpg">
```

I am not against using jquery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you need this to be done on the server, use jSoup: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is to find the position of the second paragraph end tag `/p>` then insert your image at that position with string concatenation.

```
<cfset myimg = "<div><img src='someimage.jpg'></div>" />
<cfset mycontent = '#queryvar.myvar#' />

<cfset firstMatch = find("/p>", mycontent, 0) />

<cfif firstMatch gt 0 >
  <cfset secondMatch = find("/p>", mycontent, firstMatch + 1) />
<cfelse>
  <cfset secondMatch = 0 />
</cfif>

<cfif secondMatch gt 0 >
  <cfset mycontent = left(mycontent, secondMatch + 3) 
                        & myimg 
                        & right(mycontent, (len(mycontent) - (secondMatch + 3))) />
</cfif>  

<cfoutput>#mycontent#</cfoutput>
```